# How to install Eclipse using the terminal in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, docker

I used the following commands inside docker in the following order

```
docker run ubuntu apt-get update
docker run ubuntu apt-get install eclipse-platform
docker run ubuntu eclipse
```

After which I get the following error

```
find: `//.eclipse': No such file or directory
find: `//.eclipse': No such file or directory
W: Cannot inject update-sites, cannot find the correct config.
Eclipse:
An error has occurred. See the log file
/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/1423306978620.log.
```

Can you tell me how I will be able to fix this?

Comment: No I am able to install eclipse when I try this in Ubuntu but it doesn't work when I try to do this within the docker container

Comment: I installed it directly by downloading from eclipse site...

Comment: I want to run eclipse from within the docker container which is why I am using the command "docker run ubuntu eclipse". I have been able to install eclipse from store & the site ... but I want to run it within the docker container which is possible only if I figure out what this issue is about,..

Answer (score 1):

make `wget` of the version you want in whatever folder you want.

do `tar -xf` on the file

then enter the foder and do `./eclipse`

This should do the trick

**Note:** docker might not be configured to run a graphical environment, so when you use it it might cause an error.